# Señales de Boost como métodos de instancia C++

Tags: c++

Cuando creo una clase con una señal como variable de instancia y después en el `main` intento guardar el objeto en un vector/lista/etc, me da error.

He probado a usar la librería estandar y la de vector de boost y me sigue dando error.

Básicamente hago esto:

```
//He omitido los includes y espacios de nombre para simplificar este texto

class Signalboost
{
    public:
    boost::signals2::signal<void ()> sig;

    Signalboost(){}
    ~Signalboost(){}
};
```

En el archivo del main:

```
int main ()
{

   Signalboost b;
   b.sig.connect([]{cout << "Emitiendo una señal" << endl;});
   b.sig();   

   //Creo un vector con Boost
   boost::numeric::ublas::vector<Signalboost> vBb(1);
   vBb(0) = b;

   //Pruebo con un vector de la libreria estandar de c++ 
   vector<Signalboost> vb;
   vb.push_back(b);

   return 0;
}
```

Comment: Deberías dar información sobre el error ¿No crees?

Comment: Y además, creo que las señales de boost no son copiables. Tienen el constructor de copia deshabilitado.

Comment: ¿qué tipo de error?

Comment: @Saul que error tienes? debug? depuración? algo?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

La clase `signal` no tiene implementado el constructor copia y, en consecuencia, no puedes crear una copia de la misma. En tu caso la copia se hace al añadir tu objeto al contenedor.

Tengo que mirar (no estoy con un pc ahora mismo) si la clase implementa la sintaxis move... Si no lo hace una solución es usar un puntero:

```
class Signalboost
{
public;

  typedef boost::signals2::signal<void ()> SignalType;

  Signalboost()
    : m_sig(std::make_unique<SignalType>())
  {}

  Signalboost(Signalboost&& s) = default;

  Signalboost(Signalboost const&) = delete;

  ~Signalboost()
  { }

  SignalType& Sig()
  { return *m_sig; }

private:
  std::unique_ptr<SignalType> m_sig;
};
```

Y para usarlo en un contenedor:

```
vector<Signalboost> vb;
vb.push_back(std::move(b));
```

Otra opción es usar Signalboost como un puntero y te ahorras todo lo anterior. Eso sí, tendrás que liberar la memoria manualmente:

```
Signalboost* b = new Signalboost;

vector<Signalboost*> vb;
vb.push_back(b);
```

Y para finalizar, una mejora del ejemplo anterior la consigues usando smart pointers:

```
std::unique_ptr<Signalboost> b = str::make_shared<Signalboost>();

vector<std::unique_ptr<Signalboost>> vb;
vb.push_back(std::move(b));
```

Comment: Muchisimas gracias! Llevaba semanas dandole vueltas probando cosas sin que sirvieran. He utilizado la notación de Signalboost como puntero y después liberar yo la memoria que es la que he aprendido en la universidad. Aun así muy interesante los otros aportes, los tendré muy encuenta para parender a utilizarlos. Muchas gracias de nuevo!